# Is there any concept or story of Shiva related with Jainism?

Tags: shiva, other-religions

What does the Jainism religion say about Shiva?

Do the Jains pray to Shiva or they only pray or follow their tirthankara?

Is there any concept or story of Shiva associated with Jainism?

Comment: This is off topic for our site .. if there was a Jainism.SE then this question would have been suitable there

Comment: some say that Adinath( the first tirthankar) is Adinath Shiva